# Python try except block doesn't raise correct error

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
num2hgh = Exception
txt = 'enter your grade '
while True:
    try:
        grade = int(input(txt))
        print(grade)
        if grade > 100:
            raise num2hgh
    except num2hgh:
        txt = 'Grade to high, enter again: '
    except ValueError:
        txt = 'Please enter an integer; '
    else:
        break
```

when I enter abc I don't get a ValueError I keep getting a num2hgh error.  Why? (I've been searching the internet and can't find an example)

Comment: `ValuesError` is an `Exception` so the first `except` catches it. You want to catch the most explicit exceptions before falling back to general ones

Comment: `num2hgh = Exception` is not at all how to create a custom error: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#tut-userexceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is already a ValueError in Exeption in num2hgh, according to the order of operations, since there is a ValueError in Exeption, it exits from there.

If you fix the code like this it will work

```
​

num2hgh = Exception
txt = 'enter your grade '
while True:
    try:
        grade = int(input(txt))
        print(grade)
        if grade > 2:
            raise num2hgh
    except ValueError:
        txt = 'Please enter an integer; '
    except num2hgh:
        txt = 'Grade to high, enter again: '
    else:
        break
```